# Limiting records in MySQL changes order of records?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I am trying this query to get some records:

```
select *
from `inbox`
where (
`user_id` = '00000000000000000000000000000001'
or `user_id` = '' 
and exists (
    select * 
    from `inbox_user` 
    where `inbox_user`.`inbox_id` = `inbox`.`id` 
    and `user_id`= '00000000000000000000000000000001'
))
order by inactive_percentage DESC
```

This gives me back this result:

[image: Result without limiting]

As soon as I add `limit 10` to the end it gives me this result:

[image: Result after limiting]

This doesn't make sense to me at all. According to me I should have ids 256 - 2560 but limiting changes the result and gives me the results from the end of the table. What is going on here? I tried top also but it says syntax error. How do I work around this?

Comment: What is the value for `inactive_percentage` on those rows?

Comment: fyi `where a=b or a=c and x` is not the same as `where (a=b or a=c) and x` its likely you want the latter.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that, you have a good point @AlexK.

Comment: 100 is the inactive_percentage for all